# UI - Reputation graph has a smaller gap for a certain period of days

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow, reputation, user-interface

The gap between days is smaller for a certain period of days

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

And it's reproducible in multiple user's graph

[image]

---

#### Update

Since it seems using the lib [highcharts](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts)

I searched one of their [official demos](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/chart-update)

Position with decimal is legal.

[image]

---

The steps to this:

[image]

Comment: That's because your computer display doesn't have infinite resolution. It has pixels.

Comment: @RobertLongson so .. why can not we align more uniformly to those .. how do you call them, pixels? Btw, it would make it less eye-hurting to have odd column widths that odd column gaps.

Comment: It's just a rounding effect. The steps are not *exactly* `10` and every so often often the integer increases by 9 instead of 10. It would be better to reduce the bar width by `1` when this happens, but then a sharp eye might ask "why is this bar narrower?" Similarly with a typical progress bar, it might be stepping by 1 second and every now and then it jumps by 2 seconds.

Comment: While I do see the point others are making, I think some styles should be applied to make this effect less clearly visible.